# Yarn keeps using old registry

Tags: yarnpkg

I've been using yarn with a private registry in the past - however, the registry has now shut down and I want to use yarn with the official registry.

Whatever I do, yarn always seems to want to connect to the old registry and there's simply no way of making it use the new one. I've already tried:

- Completely remove and re-install yarn
- `yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com/`
- Verified that there is no mention of the old registry in either `~/.npmrc` or `~/.yarnrc`
- Cleared the yarn cache using `yarn cache clean`

No matter what I do, yarn still tries to connect to the old registry on every install and I have no idea where yarn is getting that from...

any ideas?

Comment: `yarn cache clean` fixed a problem I was having :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it, the culprit was `~/.config/yarn/global/yarn.lock`...

Answer (score 17):

Remove your global yarn.lock
`rm ~/.config/yarn/global/yarn.lock`
and then
`yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com/`

Answer (score 1):

Running `yarn add` with `--verbose` will tell you which `.yarnrc` files are being picked up. These shouldn't include the old registry.

So run `yarn add <your-package> --verbose` and check the `.yarnrc` files found for any mention of the old registry.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got it fixed with a `rm ~/.npmrc` running MacOS

Comment: I ran `yarn add --verbose` and found the same.